# Google Charts Api Multiple charts in the same canvas

Tags: javascript, pie-chart, google-visualization

I am using google charts api. It is perfect for my needs. I am now trying to incorporate multiple pie charts in the same page. I have moved the charts to the bottom of the page. How to add four pie charts in the same canvas or should I create multiple canvas on the same page.

```
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Do not understand what you means by canvas. But if you've 4 Google charts, each chart can be displayed in its own DIV. So you'll need 4 'chart_div'. For example, this is how the [Web Reporting](http://demo3.iccube.com/icCube/doc/tutorial/ic3report-tutorial.html?ic3demo) of [icCube](http://www.icCube.com) is working.